# Which php functions act directly upon the variable? (like sort() )

Tags: php, function

Fer instance:

```
$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
$sort = sort($fruits);
var_export($sort);
var_export($fruits);
```

returns

```
true
array ( 0 => 'apple', 1 => 'banana', 2 => 'lemon', 3 => 'orange', )
```

The sort() returns only a bool, if it worked or not.  The function works on the variable, itself.
Whereas:

```
$s = 'thestring';
$trim = trim($s,'ing');
var_export($trim);
var_export($s);
```

returns:

```
'thestr'
'thestring'
```

So, what gives?  Is there a rhyme or reason for this? Which functions act directly upon the variable?

edit:
'pass by reference', I see.  Thusly:

```
function mytrimmer(&$string){
    $string = trim($string,'ing');
    return $string;
}

$s = 'thestring';
var_export(mytrimmer($s));
var_export($s);
```

returns

```
'thestr'
'thestr'
```

Comment: It's called [`pass by reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) And you see it on the signature of the function if they have an ampersand(&) in front: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php -> See the: **&** `array`

Comment: Any function that is "pass by reference", depicted in the manual description as `&$varName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to sort(), rsort() and shuffle() also act on the array variable supplied to the function.

Comment: Axly, this does answer the question. At least it provides a partial answer, I just wish there was a reference to some list of php funcs that act on a var by reference. The main problem is the question sucked.  I'm not sure what to do about that, at this point.